# Netbeans + Git - The Basics

Tags: git, unix, netbeans, ftp-server

Our situation:

We want to use git to manage our project files. So we've set up a unix server and installed git there. Then we created a dircetory and init a git repository.

On our workplace (windows pc) we installed netbeans and git to use them together.
And now the problems starts. We can clone the repository from the server via ssh but now we are stuck with understanding how git works.

How we can work with the cloned / pulled files and how we can update our changes to the server?
Here is how I understand it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCrdS.jpg

Can you answer the question on the picture as well?!

Thanks, Pete.

Comment: Documentation exists. It exists for free on the internet. It isn't guarded by fire-breathing dragons.

Comment: It's *usually* not even guarded by fire-breathing programmers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a free book titled [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book) prominently featured on the git website. It's quite good for learning what git is and how to use it.

Comment: Thanks @khagler That helps a lot. We kind of get the basics. Now we learning by doing. Here is my [new interpretation](http://i.imgur.com/wn8Er.jpg) of how git works basicly. (Not perfect but ya ...)